# InvalidEntryException : Invalid Request URI when trying to pull Google Documents for a user

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

When trying to pull documents from my application I am frequently receiving an "Invalid Request URI", InvalidEntryException.  My application has a nightly process that pulls documents for all users on many domains, some nights it works perfectly, others (on the same users) it fails with this error.  This is not domain specific, as my application runs on over 50 domains.  The following code is producing the error :

```
String docFeedUrl = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/" + USER_NAME + "/private/full/-/mine?xoauth_requestor_id=" + ADMIN_NAME;

    DocumentListFeed feed = null;
    int retry = 5;
    while (retry > 0) {
        try {
            feed = client.getFeed(new URL(docFeedUrl), DocumentListFeed.class);
            retry=0;
            } catch(Exception e){
            // handle exception
            }
```

I am using 2-legged oauth with Google Marketplace keys for authentication. Anyone have any ideas?